# TLS WebConfiguration for WebSphere MQ 8 and IBM MQ 9

Tags: websphere, ibm-mq, tls1.2, websphere-8

I've encountered a problem with setting tls on my queue manager.
Here are the commands that I've used on my windows 10 to create and setup queue manager aswell as channel and keystores.

```
"C:\Program Files\IBM\MQ\bin64\crtmqm.exe" QMTLS
"C:\Program Files\IBM\MQ\bin64\strmqm.exe" QMTLS

"C:\Program Files\IBM\MQ\bin64\runmqsc.exe" QMTLS
DEF LISTENER(TCP.1416) TRPTYPE(TCP) CONTROL(QMGR) PORT(1416) REPLACE

START LISTENER(TCP.1416)

DEF CHL(CONNECTION.TLS) CHLTYPE(SVRCONN) TRPTYPE(TCP) SSLCIPH('TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256') SSLCAUTH(REQUIRED) DESCR('Channel with tls support')

DEFINE CHANNEL (CONNECTION.TLS) CHLTYPE (CLNTCONN) TRPTYPE (TCP) CONNAME (127.0.0.1) QMNAME (QMTLS) SSLCIPH('TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256') MAXMSGL (104857600) DESCR ('Client connection to Server')
exit

cd C:\ProgramData\IBM\MQ\qmgrs\QMTLS\ssl

"C:\Program Files\IBM\MQ\bin64\runmqakm.exe" -keydb -create -db key.kdb -pw passw0rd -stash

"C:\Program Files\IBM\MQ\bin64\runmqakm.exe" -cert -create -db key.kdb -label ibmwebspheremqqmtls -stashed -size 2048 -sigalg SHA256WithRSA -dn CN=QMTLS -fips -ca false

"C:\Program Files\IBM\MQ\bin64\runmqakm.exe" -cert -extract -db key.kdb -label ibmwebspheremqqmtls -target qmtls.arm -stashed

mkdir jks
cd jks

"C:\Program Files\IBM\MQ\java\jre\bin\keytool.exe" -genkey -alias ibmwebspheremquser -keyalg RSA -sigalg SHA256withRSA -dname "cn=user@example.com,C=US" -keystore userkey.jks -storetype jks -storepass passw0rd -keypass passw0rd -validity 365 -keysize 2048

"C:\Program Files\IBM\MQ\java\jre\bin\keytool.exe" -export -keystore userkey.jks -alias ibmwebspheremquser -storepass passw0rd -file userkey.arm -rfc

cd ..
copy jks\userkey.arm userkey.arm

"C:\Program Files\IBM\MQ\bin64\runmqakm.exe" -cert -add -db key.kdb -stashed -file userkey.arm -label userkey -trust enable -fips

copy qmtls.arm jks\qmtls.arm
cd jks

"C:\Program Files\IBM\MQ\java\jre\bin\keytool.exe" -import -alias QMTLS -file qmtls.arm -storepass passw0rd -keystore userkey.jks

"C:\Program Files\IBM\MQ\bin64\runmqsc.exe" QMTLS

SET CHLAUTH('CONNECTION.TLS') TYPE(BLOCKUSER) USERLIST('*NOACCESS') DESCR('allow access to tls') WARN(NO) ACTION(ADD) 

refresh security type(ssl)

exit
```

When I try to connect directly to queue manager with channel CONNECTION.TLS and userkey.jks keystore I get an error AMQ4199 with message:

```
Queue manager QMTLS is not available for client connection due to an SSL configuration error. (AMQ4199)
Queue manager QMTLS is not available for client connection due to an SSL configuration error. (AMQ4199)
Severity: 30 (Severe Error)
Explanation: The user is trying to connect to a remote queue manager using a secure connection.
Response: Check the SSL configuration of the target queue manager and the local SSL trust store.
```

Comment: Have you tried running the TLS sample `amqssslc` that you can find in `C:\Program Files\IBM\MQ\samp\bin` ? Instructions for running can be found here -  https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.1.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q024430_.htm

Comment: I see that you have defined a CLNTCONN channel so therefore you are making use of the CCDT to give your client application the details it needs. Please can you update your question with how you provided the CCDT to your application to use. You don't say what your application is, although the error you describe is an MQ Explorer error, so I assume, and perhaps you can confirm, that your client application is in fact the MQ Explorer.

Comment: Actually, the fact that you used the term "connect directly" to queue manager, suggests that you have chosen the option "connect directly" on the MQ Explorer "Add Remote Queue Manager" dialog? If so, then you are not using the CCDT that you set up because that would be the next option "Connect using a client channel definition table". Either way, please show us the set up you did for your client application - i.e. how you told it to use the channel CONNECTION.TLS, as I suspect this is where your issue lies.

Comment: @MoragHughson Yes. I was using MQ Explorer. Later I'll use.NET application, but first I need to check if connection is working, so easiest way, in my opinion, to test connection is mq explorer. Here is the procedure I've used. I was trying to add remote queue manager. In queue manager name field I've entered QMTLS, then I've filled ip address and port number fields and I've entered CONNECTION.TLS as server connection channel. Also, I've enabled ssl key repositories and added trusted certificate store and personal certificate store (userkey.jks).

Comment: @MoragHughson  I'm not using CLNTCONN to connect to queue manager, That was one of the attempts to get mq explorer to work.

Comment: @Darman You don't mention setting the CipherSpec anywhere? Any chance you could add a screenshot or two of your setup? Also, MQ Explorer (a Java application) is not really a good test of a .NET environment. You might be better with a .NET sample so it is a closer test to what you intend to do next.

Comment: Normaly you should have additionnals logs either on MQ Server side or on MQ Explorer side. I don't see the command to setup the certificate at the qmgr level (but it might work without it). Certificate name doesn't have to follow a strict pattern since v8

Comment: @jdel - he appears to have used the default location for the key database, and the default name for the qmgr certificate, so therefore the qmgr should find what he has created.